# Simple calculation using 2 selects

Tags: javascript, laravel

It's a simple form which calculates the final fees to be charged depending on nationality and team member.

I would like to make sure all P&C are taken care of.

if both the team members and nationality are set, the fees values are shown. But if someone changes anyone value, the fees should also change.

I have a minimal understanding of Java script

```
 <div class="form-group d-flex">
   <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
   <select class="form-control" name="purpose" required="" id="toalp">
       <option value="">Number of Team Members</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group d-flex">
   <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
       <select class="form-control" name="amount" required="" id="pnationality">
            <option>Show Nationality</option>
            <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
            <option value="Foreigner">Not an Indian</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group d-flex">
  <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fees " name="fees"  required="" id="finalamt">
</div>

Java script for calculations
$('#toalp').change(function () {
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "1"){num = 1; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "2"){num = 2; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "3"){num = 3; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "4"){num = 4; }
    console.log(num)
});

$('#pnationality').change(function () {
    if ($('#pnationality option:selected').text() == "Indian"){ cost = 100; }
    if ($('#pnationality option:selected').text() == "Not an Indian"){ cost = 200; }
    z = cost*num;
    $.each(res.project_modal, function (key, value) {
    $("#finalamt").val(value.z);
    // console.log(cost);
    console.log(z);
});
```

the fees should show be multiplication of team member and nationality.
It should change whenever the fields ae changed

Comment: You should consider using a front framework like VueJS (already shipped within Laravel), its data-driven approach makes this kind of tasks easy

Comment: I will do that. Can you help in this one please as of now(). Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('#toalp').change(function () {
    calculation();
});

$('#pnationality').change(function () {
    calculation();
});

function calculation() {
    var num = 0;
    var cost = 0;
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "1"){num = 1; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "2"){num = 2; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "3"){num = 3; }
    if ($('#toalp option:selected').text() == "4"){num = 4; }

    if ($('#pnationality option:selected').text() == "Indian"){ cost = 100; }
    if ($('#pnationality option:selected').text() == "Not an Indian"){ cost = 200; }

    var z = cost*num;
    $("#finalamt").val(z);
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks a lot. You saved the day for me. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could achieve that thanks to VueJS. You may refer to this documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select .
Each `input`/`select` is bound to a Vue data thanks to `v-model` directive : when DOM data mutates, Vue data automatically mutates, and the reverse too.
Watchers allow you to specify a callback when some data changes (similarly to jQuery events, except that the callback is bound to a data instead of a DOM element, that's why it's called data-driven instead of event-driven).

```js
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            toalp: '',
            pnationality: '',
            totalCost: 0
        },
        computed: {
            parsedToalp () {
                return parseInt(this.toalp);
            },
            nationalityCost () {
                switch (this.pnationality) {
                    case 'Indian':
                        return 100;
                    case 'Foreigner':
                        return 200;
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            toalp () {
                this.totalCost = this.nationalityCost
                    ? this.parsedToalp * this.nationalityCost
                    : 0;
            },
            pnationality () {
                this.totalCost = this.parsedToalp
                    ? this.parsedToalp * this.nationalityCost
                    : 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="form-group d-flex">
        <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="purpose" required="" v-model="toalp">
            <option value="">Number of Team Members</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-flex">
        <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="amount" required="" v-model="pnationality">
            <option>Show Nationality</option>
            <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
            <option value="Foreigner">Not an Indian</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-flex">
        <label><i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fees " name="fees"  required="" v-model="totalCost">
    </div>
</div>
```